# Probability exercise with normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

So this is a question about Normal Distribution (correct me if I am wrong), but I don't know how to solve it as I don't have variance and I'm not sure about mean. Help is highly appreciated.

> Assume we have 2 candidates A and B applying for some position, and
>   we estimate that 53% of the voters prefer the candidate B. We organize a poll, asking randomly chosen 100 voters about their preferences. What is the (approximate) probability that at least the half of that polled persons will favor the candidate A? Note: You can take Φ(0.601) ≈ 0.726.

Comment: The mean of a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ is $np$ while the variance is $np(1-p)$

Comment: @Henry I know that... isn't this normal distribution?

Comment: It is explicitly a binomial distribution, however normal distributions act very similarly and so may be used to *approximate* the results for the binomial distribution, resulting in much easier calculations while sacrificing a little bit of accuracy.  (*With numbers like yours, expect the true answer to be off from the approximated answer by something on the order of magnitude of $0.0001$ or so*)

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, but what about the solution? That is ultimately what I need, I know that binomial and normal are similar

Comment: In order to get started using a normal distribution to approximate your binomial distribution, the first steps are to decide *which* normal distribution to use.  You want it to have the same mean and the same variance as your original binomial distribution, hence @Henry's comment about how to find the mean and variance of your actual binomial distribution.

Comment: To continue, you can refer to similar problems such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707355/) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154836/), refer to the wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation), self-help sites like [here](https://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/statistics/normal-approximations), or youtube lectures like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9nRcadQYsU).

Comment: Also, if more then half voters prefer B, probability of at least half voters favor A should be less than $0.5$. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: @mihaild no, no typo.  We are only polling a small number of the total population, not the whole population

Comment: @JMoravitz but median of binomial distribution is $np$ if it's integer, and it is in this case. So probability of B getting less than expected number of votes (ie less than 53) should be less than $0.5$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I just tried to solve it with $\mu=0.53*100, \sigma=0.53*100*0.47$ and $P(X\leq50)=P(Z\leq\frac{50-\mu}{\sigma^2})$, and the fraction was not equal to $0.601$... I think something is wrong here.

Comment: @TigranMinasyan $np(1 - p)$ is variance ($\sigma^2$), not standard deviation ($\sigma$).

Comment: @mihaild I didn't write $\sigma^2$, that was a typo, I wrote just $\sigma$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every vote can be seen as a bernoulli random variable, with $p=1-0.53=0.47$. Therefore the sum of the 100 votes  for candidate $A$ is binominal distributed as $S\sim Bin(100, 0.47)$. with $\mu=47$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{100\cdot 0.47\cdot 0.53}$

Now it is asked for $P(S \geq 50)$. We can use the converse probability here. $P(S \geq 50)=1-P(S\leq 49)$

By applying $\text{central limit}$ theorem we can approximate the binomial distribution by the normal distribution.

$P(S \geq 50)=1-P(S\leq 49)\approx 1-\Phi \left( \frac{49-47}{\sqrt{100\cdot 0.47\cdot 0.53}} \right)=1-\Phi(0.401)$

Now we have the problem that the lecturer expect a different value, since it was calculated $P(S \geq 50)=1-P(S\leq 50)\approx 1-\Phi \left( \frac{50-47}{\sqrt{100\cdot 0.47\cdot 0.53}} \right)=1-\Phi(0.601)$

But this is wrong since $P(X\geq x)=1-P(X\leq x-1)$, if $X$ is binomial distributed. It´s up to you how you deal with this situation.

Comment: I think the word _at least_ was just unnecessary in the problem, it should be $P(S>50)$

Comment: @TigranMinasyan I agree. "more than" would be better here.

Comment: You forgot continuity corrections.  It should have been $49.5$ rather than $49$ in the numerator.

Comment: @JMoravitz I know that I have omitted the continuity correction factor. But according to the solution they haven´t used it as well. So I decided not to use it.